# Can someone explain the line marked as "Line1" in the below code?

Tags: c++, string, stl, find

```
string replaceBlankWith20(string str) {
  string replaceby = "%20";

  int n = 0;

  // loop till all space are replaced
  while ((n = str.find(" ", n)) != string::npos)  // L1
  {
    str.replace(n, 1, replaceby);
    n += replaceby.length();
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: what do you not understand specifically? Do you know what `find` does?

Comment: If it helps, the loop could be modified into `for (n = str.find(" ", n); n != string::npos; n = str.find(" ", n))`

Comment: This code suppose to url-encode special/reserved/unsafe characters, but it does it wrong way! It encodes only spaces in very bad way. If this code is not yours: do not trust it and do not learn from it. (I'm assuming it is not yours since you are asking to explain it).

Comment: Here is [document](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2) which most probably is to technical for you, but it explains what this code supposed to do.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I have a basic understanding of find. I need the understand the parameter other than " ", which is n. What is its use

Comment: @MarekR I know what the code does. But I didnt find a single website that explains all the parameters in find function.

Comment: Is this a joke? How did you look for it? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find

Answer (score 2):

It finds the next whitespace in the string and check if it is a valid string, the code can be expanded this way for clarity

```cpp
string replaceBlankWith20(string str) {
  string replaceby = "%20"; // string to replace the space with

  int n = 0; // position of the space to replace

  // loop till all spaces are replaced
  while (true)
  {
    // find whitespace in str starting from char n
    n = str.find(" ", n);
    // be sure to not exceed string maximum length limit
    if ( n == string::npos) { 
      break;
    }

    // actually replace the space
    str.replace(n, 1, replaceby);
    n += replaceby.length();
  }
  return str;
}
```

As the comment below state `" "` is the space character whitespace are also `\t`, `\n`, `\r`, `\v`, and `\f`

Comment: A minor point: the code doesn't search for whitespace, it searches for a space character. There are other characters that are also whitespace: `'\t`', `'\n'`, `'\r`', `'\v`, and `'\f`. Those are tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab, and formfeed, respectively.

Comment: ' n = str.find(" ", n);'  What does the 'n' inside find used for. Can you suggest me a link that explains the parametrs in find in layman terms

Answer (score 0):

It searches for a substring, and if the result is found continues to execute the loop body. You could use boost for this task:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

std::string ReplaceBlankWith20(std::string const& str) {
  return boost::replace_all_copy(str , " " , "%20");
}
```